# Дуршлаг, шлагбаум — этимология

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Можно ли отнести слова "дуршлаг" и "шлагбаум" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 2):

Проведем исследование этимологии слов *дуршлаг* и *шлагбаум*.

[дуршла́г](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B4/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3)
Заимствовано из немецкого языка, где *Durchschlag* произведено от *durchschlagen* (продырявливать, пробивать насквозь) — от *durch* (через, сквозь) и ***schlagen* (ударять)**.

[шлагба́ум](https://lexicography.online/etymology/krylov/%D1%88/%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC) 
Заимствование из немецкого, в котором слово *Shlagbaum* составлено из глагола ***schlagen — «бить, ударять»*** и существительного *Baum* — «дерево». Глагол «бить, ударять» здесь подразумевает удар закрывающимся рычагом по опоре.

Сделаем вывод: слова можно признать *этимологически родственными.*
В современном же языке они однокоренными не являются (их значение и употребление совершенно различны и "не пересекаются"); корни: *-дуршлаг-* и *-шлагбаум-* (по Тихонову).

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически - да, ибо "дурхьшлаг" от "дурхь шлаген" - как бы "бить насквозь", а шлагбаум - дерево, которое бьёт. Вот и. Но на деле они друг с другом не связаны, да и глагол "шлаген" не всегда "бить".